# Location is not accurate when replicating an existing feature and zooming in

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to resolve an issue with the accuracy of a selected point using `queryRenderedFeatures`. The accuracy is fine when zoomed out, but when zooming in it appears off.

I am using the coordinates from the results of the `queryRenderedFeatures` to set the coordinates of a separate selection layer. This is the "blip" underneath the "properties" layer.

Here is the basic structure of my code:

```js
const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);

const selected = features[0].toJSON() // "properties" layer is at index 0

map.addSource('propertySelect', { // source for the selected property
                "type": "geojson",
                selected
            });

map.addLayer({"id": "propertySelect", // layer for the selected property. The "blip"
              "source": "propertySelect",
              "type": "circle"
              "circle-radius-transition": {duration: 0},
              "circle-opacity-transition": {duration: 0},
              "circle-radius": 0,
            }, 'properties');
```

**TLDR**

Setting a features coordinates based on an existing feature does not seem to match the same coordinates when zoomed in. See image below.

[image: GIF of issue]

Answer (score 2):

When you first called queryRenderedFeatures you're getting the coordinates generalised to the zoom level your map was initially at, which as you can see is a bit off the source data coordinates.

You'll either need to take the ID of the selected feature and lookup the geometry directly, or re-do your queryRenderedFeatures or querySourceFeatures after you've zoomed in.

Comment: Is there documentation that says coordinate values get generalized based on zoom level? The X Y values aren't any different when I log them at different zoom levels.

Comment: Are you using GeoJSON to load the data initially? If so, mapbox-gl-js converts the data to vector tiles using the geojson-vt library making some choices to improve performance. There is some info here https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/working-with-large-geojson-data and some of the settings from geojson-vt are exposed in mapbox-gl https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-geojson

Comment: @KristoforCarle yes the data is loaded from geojson. Adding the data to the map at "zoom end" has resolved this issue for me. I'll refer to those links for future reference.

Comment: Im wondering if this is a similar type of phenomena when the opposite has occurred in other web map solutions (ie: You are at zoom level 20, and zoom all the way out and you have say, Country boundaries turned on, and at zoom scale 5, they aren't aligned to the basemap.